# Why create multiple instance of same BroadcastChannel lead to browser freeze?

Tags: javascript, browser, freeze, broadcast-channel

Recently, I had a strange issue when using API BroadcastChannel in Chrome.
I have a tab that need data from other tab, so I used BroadcastChannel to archive this.

When user click the button, it'll trigger a `postMessage` to the destination tab that is listening the same BroadcastChannel

```
const sendData = data => {
    const broadcast = new BroadcastChannel('viewDataChannel')
    broadcast.postMessage(data);
};
// ...
<Button onClick={data => sendData(data)}>Send data</Button>
// Receiver
const broadcast = new BroadcastChannel('viewDataChannel');
broadcast.postMessage = data => setData(data);
```

Everything work fine untill it doesn't. In the production, user click on the button a lot and just after a few clicks (maybe 10 times), Chrome is freeze (high RAM and CPU usage, my application freeze too) and I had to kill browser and restart it.

I fixed it by move the code create BroadcastChannel instance to outside the function to just create it in the first time, but I did a lot of research and still not found anything that relate to create a lot of same BroadcastChannel will lead to browser freeze

Do anyone know how BroadcastChannel work and explain why this happen ?

Comment: what are the channel receivers doing?

Comment: Do you also add a listener to these BC instances? If so, your BCs are never garbage collected and their listeners will fire every time something new is posted. Would be great to have a [MCVE]

Comment: @RexHenderson updated in the question

Comment: Where are your RECEIVERS i.e. broadcast.onmessage handlers

Comment: Get that new BroadcastChannel out of your sendData method

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `sendData` method:

```
const sendData = data => {
    const broadcast = new BroadcastChannel('viewDataChannel')
    broadcast.postMessage(data);
};
```

By calling `new BroadcastChannel` here, you are attempting to create another instance every time you send data. If instead, you move this out of your `sendData` function, you will reuse the same `BroadcastChannel` on every call to `sendData`:

```
const broadcast = new BroadcastChannel('viewDataChannel')
const sendData = data => {
    broadcast.postMessage(data);
};
```

Comment: `By calling new BroadcastChannel here, you are attempting to create another instance every time you send data` => not really true, you can test it, I created a loop for create new instance every time a click button and website still run perfectly